# How do I detect programmatically in which ring (-1, 0, 1, 2, 3) I am running?

Tags: virtual-machine

How do I detect programmatically in which ring (-1, 0, 1, 2, 3) I am running?

Comment: WTF is ring -1? I remember the others from the early OS/2 and protected-mode Windows days, but -1 is a new one on me.

Comment: It's the hypervisor thingummy, for hardware virtualisation of OSs already using ring 0.

Comment: Okay, that makes sense, I guess. There were no hypervisors back when we were doing operating systems. Thanks, @onebyone.

Comment: ring negative one http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/archives/000580.html

Comment: @Andrew: what were you trying to accomplish?

Comment: @John: nothing, this is really a pure problem with no current theoretical relevance. Perhaps it's useful for writing VMware add-ons or so later.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The ring are the lower two bits of the code segment selector (CS) register in the 64-bit x86 architecture.

You can extract it like this: ([test it online](https://onlinegdb.com/Sy6YYqUqI))

```
#include <stdint.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
    uint64_t rcs = 0;
    int ring;

    asm ("mov %%cs, %0" : "=r" (rcs));
    ring = (int) (rcs & 3);
    printf("Hello, world. This program is running on ring %d!\n", ring);
    return 0;
}
```

The problem with that code is that it will always return 3, because your code will always run on ring 3. To see that changing you need to create a Linux Kernel Module or Windows Device Driver.

I have a github repo where i was playing around with [this](https://github.com/crgarcia12/containers-assembly-permissionsdemo/blob/master/demo-1/c-main.c) in Ubuntu 18. 
In the demo 1  I have the exact same code as above. You can run it:

```
cd demo-1
. c-build.sh
```

In the demo-2 I have a Linux Kernel module that will execute the same code, but inside the kernel in ring 1:

[link to code](https://github.com/crgarcia12/containers-assembly-permissionsdemo/blob/f60c17d28e57bebf6c067887b0c21cecb5f47ae6/demo-2/lkm_example.c#L14):

```
...

#define EXAMPLE_MSG "Hello, World. This is executed in ring: _ \n"

...

uint64_t rcs = 0;
asm ("mov %%cs, %0" : "=r" (rcs));
msg_buffer[MSG_BUFFER_LEN - 3] = (int) (rcs & 3) + '0';
```

You cannot do printf to the console from the kernel driver. Instead you need to open the device as a file and read from it:

```
cat /dev/lkm_example
```

I would recommend you to follow the [readme](https://github.com/crgarcia12/containers-assembly-permissionsdemo/blob/master/demo-2/readme.md) step by step, so you can see it running :)

Answer (score 7):

The easiest way is, to just run the (x86) command and catch the corresponding error.

E.g. (SEH, Windows, kernel mode)

```
bool ring_lower_0 = false;
__try
{
    __asm { <cmd> };
    ring_lower_0 = true;
}
__except( GetExceptionCode() == EXCEPTION_PRIV_INSTRUCTION )
{
    ring_lower_0 = false;
}
```

Notes:

cmd, is an assembler command. See the Intel Architecture Reference Manuals for a list of commands and their respective Ring levels.

Linux has a slightly different concept.

But remember that VMs residing on a lower level may mask the result by emulating the call.

(NB: The Job of the VM is to translate the invalid instruction into an meaningful call)

---

If you really want to check if your a virtualized and want to stop execution because of this, you should read what has been written about 'Red pill'.

Comment: Thanks. That's a very good solution. I can work from here. Mask the result: I know. I just needed some point to begin.

Answer (score 3):

Unless you're a device driver, you'll always be running in Ring 3 (for systems that have "rings", per se).

Comment: Is that so? What about deamons and programs running as root?

Comment: What if I am a device driver of an operating system running a hosted hypervisor? Wouldn't I be running in ring -1 together with the host system and the hypervisor?

Comment: deamons are user mode programs running under another account. root is another account too. 'real' drivers run in kernel mode (mostly ring 0 because ring1 + ring2 are rarely used today.

Comment: @Andrew: rude, rude. Yes, that's so.

Answer (score 1):

Normally i would write that you should read about "protected mode programming". There is an article about how to intertact with ring 0 using windows XP SP2. Note that it will change for others windows versions and for sure others operational systems.

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/threads/MinimalisticRingZero.aspx

If you just want to detect if you are running inside of a virtual machine, to avoid that people debug your application, for example, you can check here:

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/system/VmDetect.aspx